# 301 redirect using a wildcard to a single page using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

This is an excerpt from my htaccess file. I actually have more 301 redirects but this should suffice for the question. I think the top bit comes automatically from Wordpress, I certainly didn't write it.

Below the wordpress part there are a bunch of 301 redirects. In reality about 25 301s.

Within the 301s I have 3 URLs with /viz/*

Instead of having to redirect every page individually with viz/* in the URL, how do I redirect everything from with /viz* in one line of code? All pages to be redirected to /services/

```
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN 301 Redirects

Redirect 301 /viz/tapestry-threads /services/
Redirect 301 /viz/evergreen-gates-foundation-financial-challenge /services/
Redirect 301 /viz/tiny-habits-data-structure /services/
Redirect 301 /viz /services/
```

Comment: Use RedirectMatch with a regular expression. Or do it via a RewriteRule (then you will have to do it before the WP rewrites though.)

Comment: Are you able to help with this? I tried a few things from similar threads but nothing worked. My htaccess skills are limited to the Redirect 301 /landing-URL /Redirect-to-URL/

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 "^/viz" "/services/"` should probably do the trick already. (Maybe with an additional slash at the end of the pattern, if you have other URLs starting with `/viz` that you don’t want to redirect here.)

Comment: That's great, works perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: Note: **always test new redirects with 302 (temporary) first** and only change them to 301 (permanent) when you know they work. If you make a mistake in a permanent redirect, it takes some time to undo it and you could temporarily break your site.